# Geometric sum with binomial coefficient

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, geometric-series

I'm looking for any kind of formula or insight concerning

$$
f(k,N)=\sum_{n=0}^N\binom{n}{k}\lambda^n
$$

There are loads of binomial identities, so maybe I was just missing something, but I couldn't find anything yet.

---

*Addendum:*
Further assumptions on $\lambda$, i.e. $\lambda=\exp(2\pi i\alpha)$ yield to the following problem: [Gaussian like sum with binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3981397/gaussian-like-sum-with-binomial-coefficients)

Answer (score 3):

Allow me to change your notation to
$$
f(x,m,n) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\binom{k}{m}x^{\,k} } 
$$

Then a first approach would be through a double o.g.f. as
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {f(x,m,n)y^n }
  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n}
 {\left( \matrix{  k \cr   m \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} y^n } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\sum\limits_{\,k\, \le \,n}
 {\left( \matrix{  k \cr   m \cr}  \right)\left( {xy} \right)^{\,k} y^{n - k} } }
  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\sum\limits_{\,0\, \le \,j}
 {\left( \matrix{  k \cr   m \cr}  \right)\left( {xy} \right)^{\,k} y^j } }  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {1 - y}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k}
 {\left( \matrix{  k \cr   k - m \cr}  \right)\left( {xy} \right)^{\,k} }
  = {{\left( {xy} \right)^{\,m} } \over {1 - y}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k - m}
 {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k - m} \left( \matrix{   - m - 1 \cr   k - m \cr}  \right)
\left( {xy} \right)^{\,k - m} }  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {xy} \right)^{\,m} } \over {\left( {1 - y} \right)\left( {1 - xy} \right)^{\,m + 1} }} \cr} 
$$

An other way is first to express the sum as an infinite sum with the index starting from $0$, as
$$
\eqalign{
  & f(x,m,n) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\left( \matrix{  k \cr   m \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( \matrix{  n - k \cr   n - k \cr}  \right)
\left( \matrix{  k \cr   k - m \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j}
 {\left( \matrix{  j \cr   j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  n - j \cr  n - m - j \cr}  \right)x^{\,n - j} }  =   \cr 
  &  = x^{\,n} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j} {{{\left( {n - j} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n - m - j\,} } }
 \over {\left( {n - m - j} \right)!}}\left( {1/x} \right)^{\,j} }  \cr} 
$$
where $x^{\,\underline {\,k\,} }$
represents the [Falling Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)

Then we can convert it into a Hypergeometric function by putting
$$
t_{\,j}  = {{\left( {n - j} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n - m - j\,} } } \over {\left( {n - m - j} \right)!}}
$$
and determine that
$$
t_{\,0}  = {{\left( n \right)^{\,\underline {\,n - m\,} } } \over {\left( {n - m} \right)!}}
 = \left( \matrix{  n \cr   m \cr}  \right)
$$
as well that the ratio is
$$
\eqalign{
  & {{t_{\,j + 1} } \over {t_{\,j} }}
 = {{\left( {n - 1 - j} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n - 1 - m - j\,} } }
 \over {\left( {n - 1 - m - j} \right)!}}{{\left( {n - m - j} \right)!} 
\over {\left( {n - j} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n - m - j\,} } }} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {n - 1 - j} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n - 1 - m - j\,} } }
 \over {\left( {n - j} \right)^{\,\underline {\,1\,} } 
\left( {n - 1 - j} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n - 1 - m - j\,} } }}{{\left( {n - m - j} \right)} \over 1} =   \cr 
  &  = {{n - m - j} \over {n - j}} = {{j - n + m} \over {j - n}} \cr} 
$$

Therefore
$$
f(x,m,n) = x^{\,n} \left( \matrix{  n \cr   m \cr}  \right){}
_2F_{\,1} \left( {\left. {\matrix{   { - n + m,\;1}  \cr    { - n}  \cr  } \;}
 \right|\;{1 \over x}} \right)
$$

Still another way to express $f(x,m,n)$ is
$$
\eqalign{
  & f(x,m,n) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\left( \matrix{  k \cr  m \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{{k^{\,\underline {\,m\,} } } \over {m!}}x^{\,k} }
  = {{x^{\,m} } \over {m!}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {k^{\,\underline {\,m\,} } x^{\,k - m} }  =   \cr 
  &  = {{x^{\,m} } \over {m!}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{{d^{\,m} } \over {dx^{\,m} }}x^{\,k} }
  = {{x^{\,m} } \over {m!}}{{d^{\,m} } \over {dx^{\,m} }}
\left( {{{1 - x^{\,n + 1} } \over {1 - x}}} \right) \cr} 
$$

Comment: @G Cab Thanks alot for your work. I think I can follow your calculation, but I do not yet know how to make use of your results. Hypergeometric functions are quite beyond me, but I'm still playing around with your GF

Comment: @M.Charbonnier: I thought about a 3rd way to render the sum which looks interesting, depending on what you need it for

Answer (score 2):

To get a sum of about $k$ terms (opposed to $N$ originally), use $$\sum_{n=0}^N\binom{n}{k}\lambda^n=\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\frac{d^k}{d\lambda^k}\sum_{n=0}^N\lambda^n=\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\frac{d^k}{d\lambda^k}\frac{1-\lambda^{N+1}}{1-\lambda}$$ and apply [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule). This can also be viewed as a closed-form answer *for a fixed $k$*.

Comment: Great, thanks, didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

We manage to visualise the polynomial values like Pascal identities to help us zipping products pairwise,
then we try to simplify the sum of columns repectively one by one for each of both tables,

$$
\begin{matrix}
… & x^0     &    &   &   & \\
… & x^1     & P_1^1    &   &   & \\
… & x^2     & P_2^1                                  & P_2^2     &   & \\
… & x^3     & \frac{x^3-1}{x-1}                      & P_3^2     &   & \\
… & x^4     & \frac{x^4-1}{x-1}                      & \frac{xP_3^1-(3)}{x-1}  &   & \\
… & P_5^0   & \color{blue}{\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}}          & \color{blue}{\frac{xP_4^1-(4)}{x-1}}  & \color{blue}{\frac{xP_4^2-\sum_{3}}{x-1}}  & … \\
 &  &    &   &   &   &   &   & \\
\end{matrix}
$$

We stick to the blue squares,

$P_5^2= \frac{xP_4^1-(4)}{x-1} = \frac{x(x^4-1)-4(x-1)}{(x-1)^2} $

$P_5^3= \frac{xP_4^2-\sum_3}{x-1} = \frac{\frac{x^2(x^3-1)-3x(x-1)}{(x-1)^2} – \binom{3+1}{2}}{x-1} = \frac{x^2(x^3-1)-\binom{3}{1}x(x-1)-\binom{3+1}{2}(x-1)^2}{(x-1)^3} $

...

$P_n^k=\frac{x^{k-1}(x^{n-k+1}-1)-\binom{n-k+1}{1}x^{k-2}(x-1)-\binom{n-k+2}{2}x^{k-3}(x-1)^2-...-\binom{n-1}{k-1}(x-1)^{k-1}}{(x-1)^k} $

We take initially $P_n^0=x^n$ for a fix column $k<<<n$,

$S_{k,n}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} P_i^0*\binom{i}{k}$

Recalling the pascal transform used [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4352360)

$$
\begin{matrix}
S  & = & \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} P_i^0*\binom{i}{k} \\
   & = & \sum_{i=0}^{k} (-1)^{i}*P_{n}^{i+1}*\binom{n-i-1}{k-i} \\
   & = & \sum_{i=0}^{k} (-1)^{i}*\frac{x^{i-1}(x^{n-i+1}-1)-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \binom{n-k+j}{j}x^{k-j-1}(x-1)^{j}}{(x-1)^i}*\binom{n-i-1}{k-i} \\
\end{matrix}
$$

The solution is $\theta(k^2)$,
This can be proven by reccurence but the method is too long to post.