# Gaussian like sum with binomial coefficients

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients, roots-of-unity, gauss-sums

Is there any way to calculate expressions of the form

$$
f(q)=\sum_{n=0}^N\binom{n}{k}\exp({2\pi i\tfrac{n}{N}\cdot  q})
$$

where $q\in\mathbb{Q}$?

It reminds me quite alot of Gauss sums, but I don't know much about those.

---

*Addendum:*
Please find my more general question here: [Geometric sum with binomial coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3981119/geometric-sum-with-binomial-coefficient)

Comment: Are you using the convention $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $n < k$?

Comment: Yes, I do......

Comment: @metamorphy As a matter of fact I did work it out before posting this questions. But yes, I should have linked it, but that's done now

Comment: @metamorphy I' still failing to see how to advance by specifying $\lambda$ in your other post

Comment: Oh, just saw "$q\in\color{red}{\mathbb{Q}}$". This is too much to ask for - you just have *any* answer to your prior question, with no opportunity to simplify it. (And then there's no point to include $N$ in the exponent. If it were $q\in\mathbb{Z}$...)

Answer (score 0):

I presume $k$ is a positive integer, $N \ge k$, and the terms for $n < k$ are taken as $0$.

Maple says
$$ \sum_{n=k}^N {n \choose k} r^n = \frac{r^k}{(1-r)^{k+1}} - {N+1 \choose k} r^{N+1} {}_2F_1(1,N+2; N-k+2; r) $$